# Stop Tomcat from enforcing ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, tomcat

For whatever reason, Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 (I'm using no Spring, no JSP, just a plain Servlet) ignores my

```
private static final String JSON_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
response.setContentType(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE);
```

and also the redundant

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", JSON_MEDIA_TYPE);
```

and

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF_8");
```

and sends

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

which is plain wrong (as JSON is always UTF-8) and mangles my output. The request headers contain

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

I'm pretty sure, it's Tocmcat's fault, as getting

```
Content-Tipe:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

(with the intentional typo) works perfectly.

Initially, there was no filter in the `web.xml`, then I added

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AddDefaultCharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.AddDefaultCharsetFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AddDefaultCharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but without any effect.

Comment: Have you made sure to restart any affected services after editing configurations?

Comment: @bhooks I'm sure I restartet Apache and redeployed the servlet (several times). There's another filter, which got effective this way, so this shouldn't be the problem (and it should work without any filter). Note that I only care about the content, the URI is just plain ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of (potential) problems:

1) This line:

```
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF_8");
```

should be

```
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

2) You (probably) shouldn't be setting the content encoding as part of the content type:

```
   String JSON_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
   response.setContentType(JSON_MEDIA_TYPE);
```

3) If you are calling `setCharacterEncoding` and `setContentType` after calling `getWriter` / `getOutputStream`, then they will have no effect<sup>1</sup>.

---

**UPDATE**

> 2) Why?

Because:

- the javadocs don't say that you can / should set it that way, and
- it is not clear what takes precedence if you set the character encoding  via both setContentType and setCharacterEncoding (and setHeader to boot)

It is better to do things the way that the javadocs say / show ... especially if you want portability.

> 4) Why the filter doesn't work?

This is a guess: possibly because you have already set / attempted to set the encoding in the servlet?  That filter sets the >>default<< charset.

> 5) Why was it too late? Nothing has been written before.

Because the javadoc says that it is the call to `getWriter()` etc that "commits" the response header.

---

<sup>1 - That is, no effect on the response sent to the client.  The `HttpServletResponse` object is likely to reflect the calls that you have made though.</sup>

Comment: 1) That was just a typo. 2) Why? 3) That's it! Thanks a bunch! It works with `response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8")`. There are still unclear points: 4) Why the filter doesn't work? 5) Why was it too late? Nothing has been written before.